# Libx GDX scrollable with rounded overlay

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am quite new to libGDX and trying to Implement the layout shown in the picture below using the [table layout](http://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout)

The **container** a Table [Green] is composed of a Table **header** [Blue] and of a ScrollPane **body** [black items]. the body is also a table with various rows.

I am trying to have the **body** part to scroll "under" **header**. At the beginning all the items from **body** should be visible with a proper padding.

The code so far:

```
ScrollPane body = new ScrollPane(bodyTable);
header.add(headerBar).expandX().fillX();    
container.add(header).top().expandX().fillX().row();
container.add(body).fill().expand();
```

[note that the required texture are not included in the snipped].

It can scroll properly but there is is like an horizontal cut **header** and **body**, while I would like to have like a rounder effect. Wonder is this is possible using tables ? Is there any example / suggestion that can point me in the right direction ?

[image]:

Comment: I think you need two sibling tables that both fill parent, one for the header and one for the body. Put enough padding at the top of the body's table that your first row will be visible under the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit I managed to have a working version.

In Scene2d there is the [Stack widget](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d.ui#stack) that is design to stack one item over the other.

The overview of the hierarchy is:

```
Stack container = new Stack;
// the container is using all the available space 
container.setFillParent(true);  
container.add(body);
container.add(head);
stage.addActor(container);
```

The tricky part is to define the correct position of the elements inside both **head** and **body**.

So for the **head** in my implementation I have something like:

```
Table header = new Table();
Table header_container = new Table(skin);

// assign a background behind the header contents
Drawable tableBackground = skin.getDrawable("top_bg");

//some position tweaks to resize the background to the wanted height
tableBackground.setMinHeight(10);
tableBackground.setBottomHeight(30);
tableBackground.setTopHeight(10);
header_container.setBackground(tableBackground);

// headerBar is another table that contains the buttons that are in the header 
header.add(headerBar).expandX().fillX();
header_container.add(header).expandX().fillX();
head.addActor(header_container);
```

**body** is a ScollPane that contains a Table. The internal table has a Top Padding defined so it is totally visible at start. When scrolling it goes under the header part and hiding a bit.

It is working but feel that there is a too much of nesting involved, if I found a cleaner solution will update the code above.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to help but my groin difficult to understand me well, you want it in a table for example the header remains in place, while others move buttons, for example.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9cwR.png

1- add window to table and table.row();

2- add other window to table and add scroller.

will not if that's what you meant.